# Javascript push an array to a 2-dim array

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

So i have 2 single dim arrays

`array1 = [1,2,3];`
`array2 = [4,5,6];`

And an empty 2-dim array

`setArray = [[],[]];`

How am i going to push the contents of the arrays to setArray so that it looks like this... considering we don't know the length of the single dim arrays?

```
setArray = [
 [1,2,3],
 [4,5,6]
];
```

I'm working on a project and my problem looks like this. Thank you.

Comment: `setArray = [array1,array2];`

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code, it's kinda hard what you're actually trying to do. I get you're trying to create a 2 dimensional array, but how are you trying to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to push contents of the two arrays in setArray you can do something like this:
Each element of setArray will have a reference to one of the arrays.

```js
   
var array1 = [1,2,3], array2 = [4,5,6];
var setArray = [];

setArray.push(array1);
setArray.push(array2);
console.log(setArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
array1 = [1,2,3]; array2 = [4,5,6];
setArray = [array1,array2];

console.log(setArray)
```

You can do it this way too.

Comment: Thanks for upvote. If it helped you, kindly accept this as answer.